# Inkscape font != latex font

Tags: fonts, latex, inkscape

I am using inkscape to create my eps figures to be included in my latex document. Whenever an equation or a text is needed I used the Inkscape TexText.

However, I still notice a difference between fonts. How can I solve this please

Comment: Instead of rendering the tex parts in inkscape, you could export the image as pdf+latex and then the formulas would be rendered by latex while you compile your document. This will ensure that they have the same font and size as the rest of the document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz by saying render image as pdf+latex, you mean keeo the included latex expression in the inkscape generated pdf and include in my tex ?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469754/adding-latex-to-figures-from-inkscape/469759#469759 for a more in depth explanation

Comment: You're welcome! If you prefer to keep using eps instead of pdf for you figures, you could have a look at the `psfrag` package. This would allow you to place placeholders in your image which would be replaced by the real formulas during the compilation of your document.